# How to generate custom keys in EF7?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

EF7 does all the usual stuff about auto-generating auto-incrementing IDs, by adding the `[Key]` attribute to an integral key.  I found a [video](https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/Seth-Juarez/Key-Generation-Strategies-in-Entity-Framework-7) that describes an alternative strategy for generating integer keys that is natively supported by EF.

The keys in my project, however, are GUIDs.  And for the most part I want them to be generated as COMB GUIDs, so that they don't cause trouble on insertion into the clustered index.  I could set a default value of `NEWSEQUENTIALID()` on the SQL table, but we specifically want to generate the IDs in code (which is why we're using GUIDs in the first place).  So question one is: **How do we generate COMB GUIDs on a key field in EF7?**

Then there's a particular table whose ID field needs to be generated from a hash of one of its fields.  (This is so that we can rely on identical records in different environments having the same ID.)  Question two is: **How do we implement custom GUID generation on inserting records in this table?**

I tinkered in the `DbContext`'s `OnModelCreating()` method, with the `ValueGeneratedOnAdd()` method, but can't find any parameters or overloads that allow me to set up any kind of custom GUID generation.

Comment: How do you do _what_, exactly? How does inserting a record into these tables work without EF?

Comment: @CodeCaster I'm converting this project from NHibernate.  NHibernate has methods that all custom generation, e.g. `Id(x => x.BookId).GeneratedBy.Custom<GuidFromMd5HashOfIsbn>()` and `Id(x => x.BookRatingId).GeneratedBy.GuidComb();`

Comment: it is can help you https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/Seth-Juarez/Key-Generation-Strategies-in-Entity-Framework-7

Comment: @NazmulHasan Thanks, I already saw that video.  That only tells you how to do one particular kind of ID generation (batches), and it's very specific to that strategy.  I need a more generic way of generating IDs.

Comment: may be not possible this version EF . will be next :)

Comment: What's not working about your current approach?

Comment: @RowlandShaw Are you asking why we're migrating from NHibernate?  That's out of the scope of this question.  What's not working in EF?  Well - I don't currently have any way to generate the IDs, and I want to find out how to do it.

Comment: I mean what have you tried? You have to put more effort in to make a key that is database generated than to mark it as a key that you'll handle yourself (be it in the property accessor or constructor, etc.)

Comment: @RowlandShaw Haven't tried anything beyond looking for an alternative method to `.ValueGeneratedOnAdd()` (and not finding one)

Comment: Do you mean something like [the `[key]` attribute](http://ef.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modeling/keys.html)?

Comment: @RowlandShaw The `[Key]` attribute, left to its own devices, just generates an auto-incrementing key(for integer keys).  My keys are Guids, anyway.  I want those keys to be auto-generated as COMB Guids for the most part, and in one particular case, it must be generated from a hash of some field values.

Comment: @RowlandShaw why is this question off topic?  It's exactly what a SO question is supposed to be, i.e. a problem that can be solved with code?

Comment: @ShaulBehr "How can I implement a facebook-like social network from scratch" is also a problem that can be solved with code, that doesn't mean it's a good fit for SO. I have no opinion about your question, just adding some perspective

Comment: @TimCastelijns just revised my question.  Is that better?

Comment: Well, you are actually asking 2 questions. Is there a way to split them up, perhaps by ask 2 questions?

Comment: @TimCastelijns the two questions are very closely related, i.e. how to generate a custom GUID key?  I'd think it's a waste to ask two separate questions, no?

Comment: There's nothing in the documentation that flagging as a [key] makes it auto-incrementing (and this is how I use it)